# spring cloud config client not loading configuration from config server

Tags: spring, cloud, config

I am following this link:
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_client_side_usage

I tested this again and again and not seeing Spring cloud client is loading configuration from cloud server, please help to see where is the error:

POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Application:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class ConfigclientApplication {
    
    @Value("${spring.cloud.config.uri}")
    String url;
    
    @Value("${production.host}")
    String host;
    
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Host is  => " + this.host ;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigclientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.properties:
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888

1. The config server is good:
   http://localhost:8888/spirent/default

```
{
  "name": "spirent",
  "profiles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "label": "master",
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "classpath:/spirent.yml",
      "source": {
        "production.host": "server1",
        "production.port": 9999,
        "production.value1": 12345,
        "test.host": "server2.com",
        "test.port": 4444,
        "test.value": "hello123"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

2. now http://localhost:8080/ can not be started at all.

   Error creating bean with name 'configclientApplication'
   It seemed the auto inject of @Value can not find the production.host environment value.

How can I read the configuration in client once loaded from config server?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are following a tutorial then follow a tutorial. The tutorial mentions that you should use the `spring-cloud-starter` dependency not the `spring-cloud-config-client`. For the application it doesn't matter where the configuration comes from, they are just properties which you can access like any other property through the `Environment` or with `@Value`.

Comment: I changed to both client or starter, but can not find out configuration value in the config server, any idea?

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue, the problem I am facing is the properties from config server are begin read from the method if it annotated with @RequestMapping but not otherwise. not sure what can be done in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Deinum implies, I'd ensure you have the client configured with the *parent* as spring-cloud-starter-parent and give it a version.  Maven plugins provided by spring cloud wont work when you include in your dependencies and remember cloud is a different project than boot.  Change it to:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Second, as a new discipline (and likely not your problem here), I'd use the new annotation on your Application instead of @Configuration and @EnableAutoConfiguration

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

Third, double check you have @EnableConfigServer on your config server

Fourth, be sure your bootstrap.properties on your client has your spring application name specified:

```
spring.application.name=spirent
```

Finally, if you used the spring-cloud-config example project, there is a default user and security password that you have to set in your URI:

```
http://user:ddf4757e-0077-42e4-b2ad-2ae04340b08c@localhost:8888
```

Otherwise, try starting from the spring-cloud-config project located here to ensure your config server is setup correctly:

```
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config
```

Comment: Thank you @RubesMN, the crucial fix is adding: spring.application.name=myapp to bootstrap.properties, and then I can see - {"profiles":[],"configService:classpath:/myapp.yml":{"my.otherprop":"myotherval"}," from /env. Now, can you answer another question, how can I access the config value in config client? I tried @Value(${profiles}) and the code can not start, complaining the injection is wrong. Thanks

Comment: You would access using a variable declaration annotated with `@Value("${my.otherprop}")` or via a class annotated with `@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")` containing a variable called 'otherprop'.  Be sure to mark the answer as correct for others to view.

Comment: I also notice that `@Value` annotated variables do not get refreshed unless the spring component they are contained within has `@RefreshScope` and a call to the client's /refresh endpoint is called.  Neither `@Value` nor `@ConfigurationProperties` config values get refreshed from the config server when /env is called as is written in the documentation.

Comment: I think I am missing something here. I am following this code here (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/svn-config-server) and the config server is running in another host, so I changed the bootstrap.yml and pointed the URI to the new host. My @Value doesnt work and the client application does not boot, "Could not resolve placeholder".

Comment: Seems within the client you do have `spring.cloud.config.uri` configured so you are good there.  Ensure you also have `spring.cloud.config.enabled: true` as well.  Although this would not stop it from starting, check your actual properties are set properly for SVN.   Finally, on client, make sure your top end class (typically called Application) has the correct annotations.  `@SpringBootApplication @RefreshScope`.  Hope this helps

Comment: Should the spring boot cloud config client be always a Rest client?. I have a Jms spring boot config client. The properties @Values are null when it fetches from spring cloud config server. It works for Rest client.

Answer (score 42):

If you are using the 2020.0.0 version of Spring Cloud then you need to add this dependency to your maven dependencies to enable config bootstrap, which is disabled by default in 2020.0.0.

[Breaking changes in 2020.0.0](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes)

This worked for me.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 25):

For those getting here after using the default Maven Spring Cloud dependency version related to Spring Boot to 2.4.0 or 2.4.1 (e.g., 2020.0.0-M5 for Spring Boot 2.4.0), besides following RubesMN's good advice, be aware that bootstrapping is not enabled by default in such Spring Cloud dependency. According to the [Spring Cloud 2020.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes):

> Bootstrap, provided by spring-cloud-commons, is no longer enabled by default. If your project requires it, it can be re-enabled by properties or by a new starter.
>
> - To re-enable by properties set spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true or spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true. These need to be set as an environment variable, java system property or a command line argument.
> - The other option is to include the new spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap (in your POM file).

I used the second option and worked just fine.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using 2020.0.0 version of spring cloud then you need to add this dependency in your maven dependencies to enable bootstrap, which is disabled by default:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Machan, Thank you ban man dawas ganak kattak kawa, Me dependancy eka nattam config server ekata connect wenne  naha. Thanks ban.

Answer (score 7):

I am adding my findings. For me, after spending healthy 2 hours I found that,

- Config Server should have: [*`spring-cloud-config-server`*]

  ```
  <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.3</version>
       <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
       </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ```
- Client Services should have: [*`spring-cloud-starter-config`*]

  ```
  <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.3</version>
       <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
       </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ```
- Client Services should declare: in *`application.properties`* or *`application.yml`*

  ```
  #This does not work
  #spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8880/config-server
  spring.application.name=name-by-which-properties/yml-file-is-created
  spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://host:port/application-context
  management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
  ```

What did not work for me:

- Adding `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap`
- Adding `spring-cloud-starter-parent`

Hope this will help others like me with `Spring Boot (2.5.3)` and `Spring Cloud 2020.0.3`

Answer (score 1):

In case, anyone is facing this issue on PCF (with marketplace config-server) even after adding `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` for new spring boot versions, make sure following dependency is added as well -

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue. I fixed it by moving the application name inside the client as client always looks up to the file which is similar to its service name.

Make sure your application name is defined in client app.
Make sure the name of service should be same as the file name in config server.

Example - I've a `order-service` and the file name is `order-service.properties`

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with `spring-boot` versions. `Spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency doesn't work well with the older spring-boot version. Try changing your `spring-boot` version to some latest version probably above `2.4.0`.

The following `gradle` implementation worked for me:

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
id 'java'
```