# Spring Cloud Client not fetching configuraiton from spring cloud server

Tags: java, spring, client-server, spring-cloud, spring-framework-beans

I am new to Spring Cloud and I am trying to connect a server and client, using a property file stored on github.

My server application.yml file is configured as follows:

```
---
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/JonEasy/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls.git
          #username: uname
          #password: pass
          search-paths:
            - 'station*'
          repos:
            perf:
              pattern:
                - '*/perf'
              uri: https://github.com/JonEasy/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls-perf.git
              search-paths:
                - 'station*'
```

The github repos are linked here [Main Properties](https://github.com/JonEasy/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls.git) and [Alternative Properties](https://github.com/JonEasy/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls-perf.git)

My client application has the following setup

```
spring.application.name=s1rates
spring.profiles.active=default
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.enabled= true
```

And the Rest Controller is :

```
@Controller
public class RateController {

    @Value("${rate}")
    String rate;

    @Value("${lanecount}")
    String lanecount;

    @Value("${tollstart}")
    String tollstart;


    @RequestMapping("/rate")
    public String getRate(Model m) {

        m.addAttribute("rateamount", rate);
        m.addAttribute("lanes", lanecount);
        m.addAttribute("tollstart", tollstart);

        //name of the view
        return "rateview";

    }
}
```

All the ${variables} van be found inside the properties file located in the git repositories.

The server is executing fine but the Client is giving me the following error

> Error creating bean with name 'rateController': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
> 'rate' in value "${rate}"

Also note that my spring application name "s1rates" is matching the properties files inside my main repository under station1/s1rates.properties.

Any hint?

Comment: Are you sure your client actually connects to the config server?

Comment: I think the reason is that I am missing bootstrap dependency...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring cloud config client not loading configuration from config server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016868/spring-cloud-config-client-not-loading-configuration-from-config-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016868/spring-cloud-config-client-not-loading-configuration-from-config-server) post helpful.

However I will consolidate my findings here.

Make sure your spring cloud client has correct pom.xml file.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2020.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

and add dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Rest all properties given in multiple posts, are generally fine.

For example in client bootstrap.properties file

```
spring.application.name=s1rates
spring.profiles.active=default
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.enabled= true
```