# No spring.config.import property has been defined

Tags: spring-cloud-config

While creating Spring Boot cloud config application getting below error.
Any help on this?

```
No spring.config.import property has been defined
 
Action:

Add a spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration.   
If configuration is not required add spring.config.import=optional:configserver: instead.
To disable this check, set spring.cloud.config.enabled=false or 
spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false.
```

Answer (score 213, accepted):

**Solution for Maven**

Add the below dependency in the `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Solution for Gradle**

Add in the `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap')
```

That resolved my issue.

Comment: this doesn't work for version 3.0.3; the specified dependency is anyway already used by `<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>`

Comment: For anyone still having this issue, this answer is no longer up-to-date, SpringBoot 2.4 or newer recommends using the `spring.config.import` property and there is no need to include another dependency unless your preferred way is to use bootstrap.yml. See [@Justin Cranford's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68668500/5492826) and [@shubh gaikwad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67744529/5492826) answers below for more info.

Comment: @emrekgn this is the best solution, just a simple pom add. `spring.config.import` will show as `unknown property` and there's no way to point the config server anywhere other than `localhost:8888`. I've read the documentation and tried setting URL both ways but it will only resolve to localhost. Tried in application.yml and boostrap.yml

Comment: @PhilipRego I'm not sure but maybe it was related to the version you were trying? We're currently using *spring-cloud-config-server v3.0.4* in prod env, and config-server pulls configs from some gitlab.com URL and other microservices access this config-server by setting `spring.config.import: "configserver:http://<some-custom-hostname>"` (not localhost) in their *application.yml*.

Comment: @emrekgn do I need to update my config-server? I just upgraded a client app
`spring-cloud-config-client` v3.0.4

Comment: @PhilipRego Which version are you using for config-server? Maybe it'd be best if you use the same version for both of them.

Comment: Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30016868/8719655

Comment: I had to add the version of this dependency as well. 
One more thing, this works for:
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul 
and not for:
spring-cloud-netflix-zuul

Answer (score 107):

You're getting this error because **you're using a new version of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud**, but **you're trying to configure it in the old way.**

### The Reason

[Spring Cloud Config Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_spring_cloud_config_client) has changed and technically `bootstrap.properties` and `bootstrap.yml` **files are deprecated**.

### Correct Solution

1. Move all properties from `boostrap.properties` to `application.properties` (it can be `.yml` as well)
2. Remove `bootstrap.properties` file
3. Replace `spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888` with  `spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888`

*This is a proper way to tell you Spring Boot app that you want to **load properties from the Spring Cloud Config service** that is running on `localhost:8888`.*

### Legacy Solution

In case you want to use a legacy `bootstrap.properties` file, you just need to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

*Please note that this is a **deprecated mechanism**, so if you're creating a new project, **go ahead with the correct solution**.*

Comment: Seems odd that it's deprecated when [other parts of the docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#:~:text=To%20modify%20the%20startup%20behavior%2C%20you%20can%20change%20the%20location%20of%20the%20config%20server%20by%20using%20bootstrap.properties) still reference it

Comment: Hello, i tried the legacy solution and got an error : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface BootstrapRegistryInitialize : ConfigClientRetryBootstrapper

Answer (score 49):

Root cause is Spring Boot 2.4 changed its default functionality. A new `spring.config.import` property is mandatory.

To fix, add the new `spring.config.import` property. Here is an example of what worked for me in `application.yml`.

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:"
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#config-data-import) is the documentation in case you need to set a different value:

> Spring Boot Config Data Import
>
> Spring Boot 2.4 introduced a new way to import configuration data via the spring.config.import property. This is now the default way to bind to Config Server.

Comment: `spring.config.import` will show as `unknown property` and there's no way to point the config server anywhere other than `localhost:8888`. I've read the documentation and tried setting URL both ways but it will only resolve to localhost. Tried in application.yml and boostrap.yml

Answer (score 21):

Importing configuration since Spring Boot 2.4 is done by `spring.config.import` functionality.

Adding below to `application.properties` connects to the default config server URL `http://localhost:8888`.

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:
```

or yml:

```
spring.config.import: "optional:configserver:"
```

More configuration options are described in the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/#config-data-import) documentation.

Legacy bootstrap functionality is still available if you add the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` dependency to your project.

Answer (score 15):

Add `bootstrap.yml` file:

```yaml
spring:
    cloud:
      config:
        enabled: true
        uri: http://localhost:9296
```

where 9296 is your cloud-config server port

and add below dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If above doesn't work, simply add below properties to your `application.yml` file to stop the port check at place as you've already defined that in `bootstrap.yml`

```yaml
spring:
    cloud:
      config:
        import-check:
          enabled: false
```

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this issue while implementing `spring-cloud-config` client.
I have added `bootstrap.yml` to specify config server address.

Later on, added the below code in `application.yml` itself which resolved the issue.

```yaml
spring:
   application:
    name: user-service
   config:
     import: optional:configserver:http://localhost:9004
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Spring Cloud Config Server on port 8191 on localhost, Spring version 3.1.0 and Java 17

I have 2 answer for this

1. Change the `application.yml` like bellow

```
spring:config:import: configserver:http://localhost:8191
```

In this case I don't have bootsrap.yml file

2. Add new dependency to pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And add `bootstrap.yml` file, my bootstrap file in that case like

```
spring:cloud:config:uri: http://localhost:8191
```

Answer (score 2):

Error message itself has suggestions / action towards the solution:

```
Add a spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration.

If configuration is not required add spring.config.import= optional:configserver: instead.

To disable this check, set spring.cloud.config.enabled=false 

or

spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just import this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Note:** SNAPSHOT, M1, M2, M3, and M4 releases typically WORK IN PROGRESS. The Spring team is still working on them, Recommend NOT using them.

Answer (score 1):

In SpringBoot v2.7.1 this solution worked for me:

My Microservice `bootstrap.properties` file:

```
spring.application.name=microservice-name
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888 # the URL of your server configuration
```

And add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is passing this error on spring-boot 2.7.0 version during tests phase put the following on src/test/application.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
```

If don't want to use config server for tests.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this dependency resolved my issue too:
spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I got past the error by removing dependency `spring-cloud-starter-config`.  If you keep it, then it will keep prompting. I think with newer Spring Boot we do not need the dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`bootstrap.properties`:

```
spring.application.name=config-client-app
eureka.client.server-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:
```

Spring version I'm working with:

```xml
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
```

Comment: Why did you need to remove the starter dependency? [Spring doc here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_client_side_usage) specifically uses it to configure the config client. Did you maybe forget to include `spring-cloud-dependencies` bom?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring Cloud Config Server  on port 8888 on localhost, Spring version 2.5.4 and Java 16

My bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.application.name=hr-worker
# Server Config
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.uri= http://localhost:8888
```

To stop to get error, i've just put this configuration in my application.properties:

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
```

Answer (score 0):

I got past the error using a version of spring 2.4.4 I was working in that moment with 2.5.1

application.properties:

```
`
spring.application.name=testserv
spring.profiles.active=prodtest
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8071

spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8071

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

eureka.instance.preferIpAddress = true 
eureka.client.registerWithEureka = true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry = true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8070/eureka/

`
```

<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>

Answer (score 0):

1- for maven add:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
```

2- for gradle add:

```
dependencies{ implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'}
```

3- in application.properties replace(old configuration):

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

by this:

```
spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888
```

Answer (score 0):

After applying any of the solutions mentioned for this question. You can give this a try:

**Step 1:** If on IntelliJ IDE, right-click on the *'pom.xml'* file of the project.

**Step 2:** Find *'Maven'* on the context menu. Then click on *'Reload project'*.

**Step 3:** Next, try *'mvn clean install'* and try running once again.

*PS: I am still looking for the reason how it worked for me. (Maybe maven related)*

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring Boot 3.0.3 version, to solve this problem simply add in the application.properties file

spring.cloud.config.enabled=false

It will read the configuration from your local properties file and not from GIT repository if you have configured.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

cloud:
config:
uri: http://localhost:9296(Your port no)

this works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

maven clean install will resolve the problem. It worked for me.

Comment: [This answer was already provided nearly a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74834077/354577). Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to application properties this worked for me change ports as needed

```
spring.application.name=exchange-service
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8001
server.port=8001

spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
```

Answer (score -1):

For spring version > 2.6.6
add below property in application.property.

spring.application.name=...      //name of application

spring.profiles.active=prodtest

spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8071

spring.cloud.config.enabled=true

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8071

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

eureka.instance.preferIpAddress = true

eureka.client.registerWithEureka = true

eureka.client.fetchRegistry = true

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8070/eureka/