# Unable to load config data from optional:configserver:http//localhost:8012

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**I have developed a users microservice and it acts as a client to spring config server but while starting users microservice it is giving below error. Could you help me to get ride of this issue**

**Erro stack**
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'optional:configserver:http//localhost:8012'at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:128) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]

**pom.xml**

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users</groupId>
    <artifactId>PhotoAppApiUsers</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PhotoAppApiUsers</name>
    <description>Users micro service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.5.3</vaadin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-config-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>```

**application.properties file of users microservice**
gateway.ip=192.168.56.109
token.expiration_time = 86400000
token.secret = hfgry463hf746hf573ydh475fhy5
login.url.path = /users/login

spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http//localhost:8012
````

Answer (score 8):

```
The issue has been resolved by just replacing the below dependency 

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>

instead of

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Didn't fully understand the issue, but can help with what we were doing to fetch config from a config server for a certain microservice.

as in your case, users microservice will have a dependency like this in pom.xml

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And project will have a file called `bootstrap.yml` or `bootstrap.properties` as below

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: user-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: <config-server-url>
      username: <if-exists>
      password: <if-exists>
```

hope this will be helpful to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Mohan for your response. Actuall Spring config server is working fine it returns confiration while i am directly testing from postman but user micro service required to get config propertis from config server. while starting user service it is giving error. I am using spring boot 2.4.5 version it doesn't require bootstrap.properties

Comment: I tried by adding your specified dependency but still same error

Comment: ok, did you set spring.application.name as per the file name you have in config server
eg: `{spring.application.name}-{profile}.properties`

Comment: Below are the config server properties

Comment: spring.application.name=PhotoAppAPIConfigServer
server.port=8012
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/balanjaneyulu....
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=XXXXXXX
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master

Comment: I am not using profile based properties file , it has only application.properties

Comment: when i calling directly from postman then config server returning below response

Comment: "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "https://github.com/balanjaneyulu23/PhotoAppConfiguration/file:C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config-repo-8473851427074645327\\application.properties",
            "source": {
                "gateway.ip": "192.168.57.109",
                "token.expiration_time": "86400000",
                "token.secret": "hfgry463hf746hf573ydh475fhy",
                "login.url.path": "/users/login"}

Comment: "name": "https://github.com/balanjaneyulu23/PhotoAppConfiguration/file:C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config-repo-8473851427074645327\\application.properties",

Comment: this file config-repo-8473851427074645327 gets created automatically whenever i make a request from ostman

Comment: With Spring Boot 2.4, you can use spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:<port> as new way of importing config data refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67507452/no-spring-config-import-property-has-been-defined for more details

Answer (score 0):

but it seems there is an issue with  "name": "https://github.com/balanjaneyulu23/PhotoAppConfiguration/file:C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\config-repo-8473851427074645327\application.properties"

Answer (score 0):

In your app.properties or JAVA_OPTS end your path with / such that its not read as a file

`-Dspring.config.location=/app/etc/`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see i got same error.

[image]

In maven panel its clearly shows that main reason of error is `dependency`. You have to import correct version of dependencies.

First thing you have to do is make sure that your config server is up.

For example you have `xxx-dev.yml` in your config file. You have to access this config file with http://localhost:8888/xxx/dev. (in this example config server process on port 8888)

If your config server up then you should check your dependencies & properties file in your project which will use config server.

Your project `application.properties` file

```
# APPLICATION NAME
spring.application.name=xxx

# PROFILE
spring.profiles.active=dev

# CONFIG SERVER
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
```

Your project `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Do not forget the add `spring-cloud.version` property into the pom.xml file. It will help you to import correct version of config client.

```
...
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties> 
...
```

After correcting the dependency it will be work fine.