# How to integrate config server in spring boot applicaton? getting error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

I am trying to integrate config-server service into my spring boot application with multiple services. After adding the changes for config server I am getting below error

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

No spring.config.import property has been defined

Action:

Add a spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration.
If configuration is not required add spring.config.import=optional:configserver: instead.
To disable this check, set spring.cloud.config.enabled=false or
spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false.

I have already tried adding dependency for bootstrap as below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But it did not work

Can someone tell me how to integrate config server in spring boot application?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67507452/no-spring-config-import-property-has-been-defined