# ERROR --- [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am disabling spring cloud configuration in bootstrap.yml in gradle project as below:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
```

But still getting this error when running Spring Boot application:

```
2023-07-03 00:30:27.370 ERROR   --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor$ImportException: No spring.config.import set
    at org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[No spring.config.import property has been defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67507452/no-spring-config-import-property-has-been-defined)

Solution for Maven

Add the below dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
Solution for Gradle
```

Add in the build.gradle file:

```
implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap')
```

Comment: Its not coming in local, local build is getting completed,

Jenkins build is getting failed while deploying the code, Any idea why it is getting failed

Comment: @SaiGangadhar: Have you tried Wiping out the workspace of Jenkins before build ? 
There are some weird instances when a newly added dependency doesn't get downloaded in Jenkins.